# Another one: Rails 4: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formhelper

I'm receiving a "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error when trying to make a form for a new company account. I've studied the answers to similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but they don't seem to address the issue that I'm having, since I made sure to have an instance of the CompanyAccount model in my CompanyAccountsController#new action.

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

The CompanyAccountsController:

```
class CompanyAccountsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @company_account = CompanyAccount.new
    end

    def create 
      @company_account = CompanyAccount.new(company_account_params)

      if @company_account.save
         flash[:notice] = "New customer created."
         redirect_to root_url
      else 
         flash[:error] = "Something went wrong."
         render "new"
      end
    end
 end
```

views/company_accounts/new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="well bs-component">

    <h2>Add New Customer</h2>

    <%= form_for(@company_account) do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label 'Name'%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label 'State' %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :state  %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success', id: 'submit_customer', value: 'Save customer' %>
      </p>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Routes:

```
company_accounts POST   /company_accounts(.:format)          company_accounts#create
new_company_account GET    /company_accounts/new(.:format)      company_accounts#new
edit_company_account GET    /company_accounts/:id/edit(.:format) company_accounts#edit
 company_account GET    /company_accounts/:id(.:format)      company_accounts#show
                 PATCH  /company_accounts/:id(.:format)      company_accounts#update
                 PUT    /company_accounts/:id(.:format)      company_accounts#update
                 DELETE /company_accounts/:id(.:format)      company_accounts#destroy
            root GET    /                                    company_accounts#index
```

Right now my solution is to use

```
<%= form_for(CompanyAccount.new) do |f| %>
```

to solve this problem, as suggested in the answer to many similar questions here. I do think this seems a little bit hacky and I'm overlooking what is really wrong. I'd very grateful if someone could help me out with this one.

Comment: Is this the whole controller's code? Because then no `company_account_params` is set.

Comment: No, it's not the whole code. I've just not added the company_account_params method. It looks like this `def company_account_params
    params.require(:company_account).permit(
              :name, 
              :state )
  end`

Comment: Just asking, because this might have been a problem. What does your model file look like? Is the database set up? Can you access the company accounts table? And as @m4risU mentioned, do you have a callback, like `set_company_accounts` and let it populate data with a `before_action`? If so, make sure, you put an exception on it, or otherwise let it only populate the necessary methods of your controller. This might be another problem.

Comment: Alexander, thanks for your effort. To answer your questions. The model just looks like a generic model. I didn't add anything. The database is set up and I can access the company_accounts table from the rails console. I'm not using a callback, also I'm not using any before_action methods. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace of the error? (it's usually 20-30 lines of filenames) that *might* helps us pin down where the error is coming from.

Comment: Also - the code that you have here - did you directly copy/paste it? sometimes a typo in the name of the @-variable can cause this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The code here is 100% correct. Please check your Application controller whether you are not overriding the value of @company_account anywhere

Comment: There's no code added to the ApplicationController, it just has the default code.